# HTML5 Video in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, html5-video

I want to call a video in ajax query, it work but not corectly (It lacks the control buttons of the video player)
Here is my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    context: document.body,
    url: "/?get=json&act=video", 
    type: "get", 
    success: function(html) {  
          // console.log(JSON.parse(html)); 
          var a = JSON.parse(html);
          var returnVideo = "";
          a.forEach(function(element) {
          console.log(element);

            returnVideo += '    <div class="uk-card uk-card-hover uk-card-default">';   
            returnVideo += '        <div class="uk-card-media-top">'; 
            returnVideo += '    <video  width="" height="">';   
            returnVideo += '        <source src="'+element.gameClipUris[0].uri+'" type="video/mp4">';   
            returnVideo += '    </video>';  
            returnVideo += '        </div>';    
            returnVideo += '    </div><br />';  

          });
          $('#loading').hide("slow");
          $('#retourForm').append(returnVideo);
        }
});
```

The output:
[image]

It lacks the control buttons of the video player!
I have test to add player with url hardcoded and it work (right in image)...

[image]

So I guess I can not load html5 player from javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `controls` attribute to the `video` tag like `<video controls></video>`. For more info read about [video tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924820(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @Julien Glad to help!